# How to insert Array<Struct> values in Impala?

Tags: cloudera-cdh, impala, complextype

I am trying to populate Complex data structure - Array data type in Impala table, currently I am using CDH 5.5, really not sure how can populate the column with some data . for ex :

```
create table arrstructex(
  name string,
  array< 
    struct<
      id:string,
      passcode:string,
      isprevileged:boolean
    >
  >
)
```

Answer (score 1):

I formatted your question a little so that I could read it.  I think there's a syntax error: the array needs to have a name.  It's also possible that the SQL parser needs a space before characters.

I would suggest you get into the habit of using upper-case for SQL keywords, and indenting.  So following the [example here](http://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-5-x/topics/impala_complex_types.html)

```
CREATE TABLE array_struct_example
(
  name STRING
  , credentials ARRAY < STRUCT <
      id: STRING
    , passcode: STRING
    , is_privileged: BOOLEAN
  >>
)
```

I added the name `credentials` and also corrected misspelling.

Answer (score 1):

The INSERT statement currently does not support writing data files containing complex types (ARRAY, STRUCT, and MAP). To prepare Parquet data for such tables, you generate the data files outside Impala and then use LOAD DATA or CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE to associate those data files with the table. Currently, such tables must use the Parquet file format.

See the documentation for insert statement: [cloudera_5.15_insert](https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-15-x/topics/impala_insert.html)