# Insert data into an impala table with struct type

Tags: sql, impala

I have a table with detailed rows (for 1 id many rows). For this reason I have created a table with struct types in order to reduce the rows and make them 1 id 1 row.

How can I insert data into an impala table with struct types? Also, how can I aggregate after values from a struct type?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using struct to store multiple values, you can use `group_concat(col, separator)`

For example, if a customer has 3 account numbers and you want to store them in 1 row separated by comma, you can use below code -

```
select cust_id, name, group_concat(cust_acc,',') as concat_account
from cust_details
group by 1,2
```

You can use pipe if your data has comma in it.
Another benifit of above solution is, you can use `split_part(concat_account,',',1)` to get first account number.

Now, if your data is very complex and you cant use group concat, you can use struct. Its little tricky because you have to prepare data first in the struct format and then load them. Pls refer to below link - [How to insert Array<Struct> values in Impala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38334987/how-to-insert-arraystruct-values-in-impala)